# /scripts/installimagemagick is now deprecated

Tags: svn, imagemagick, redmine, whm

I am trying to install Redmine With SVN following [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/installation-of-redmine-with-svn-on-a-cpanel-centos-5.6-server) article.
But when i run **/scripts/checkimagemagick** this commend it's showing

**-bash: /scripts/checkimagemagick: No such file or directory this error.**

and when i run **/scripts/installimagemagick** it showing:

**info [installimagemagick] scripts/installimagemagick is now deprecated. The ImageMagick from your distro will now be installed.**

convert --version is working fine. its showing

**Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2014-02-10 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC**

I am trying to install it on Centos 6.4 x64 VPS server where WHM is installed.

I can't install Redmine due to this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip that steps because imagemagick is already installed on your server

> Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2014-02-10 Q16 OpenMP
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC